# C++ execution time in multi-threaded multi-user environment

Tags: multithreading, timer

We are running a multi-threaded code on a server that is shared among several users.

Wall-clock timing gives us very unstable results that vary significantly from one run to another.

We also don't want to use CPU timing because that sums up the runtime values for different threads while we need to see the effect of parallelism on speedup. That requires us to time the program as a whole, but at the same time singling it out from other processes sharing the server.

Would you please suggest a proper timer for out purpose?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there an option to do your timing measurements on a separate computer that isn't being shared by other users?  If so, that would allow you to get reasonably accurate results from wall-clock timing (assuming your calculations are lengthy enough to avoid clock-granularity issues, of course).

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy. Maybe that is the best option for us right now. We are considering that. Thank you again